# Angular2 handle click in parent of recursive children

Tags: recursion, typescript, angular

I created a dynamic recursive (tree)node component which built by a json resonponse from the server. The request and response handled in tree component. I try to handle all child click event in my app. Later I like to use a child-routing which allow to load content page with the clicked node's data.

*I just started to play with angular2 so let me know if you thought this is a completly wrong concept at all :)*

tree.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tree',
    template: '
        <div (click)="onClick($event)" class="tree">
            <node *ngIf="data" [key]="key" [data]="data"></node>
        </div>
    ',
    ...
})
export class TreeComponent {
    key: string;
    data: any;
    error: any;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.key = 'tree';
        let url = 'http://localhost:53494/api/tree';

        this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            value => this.data = value,
            error => this.error = error);

    }
    ...
    onClick($event: any) {//This will recieves all click of all node!
        $event.preventDefault();

        //1. How to get the clicked node's key and data here?
        //2. How to (sub/child)route to './tree/' + [node].key?
    }
    ...
}
```

node.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'node',
    directives: [NodeComponent], //<<< use self!
    template: '
        <a href="" class="node collapsed" 
           [attr.data-toggle]="data.node ? 'collapse' : null" 
           [attr.data-target]="'#' + nodePath" 
           aria-expanded="false" >               
           <span class="ident-{{level}}">
              {{data.name || key}}
           </span>
        </a>
        <div [id]="nodePath" class="tree collapse">
           <node *ngFor="#nodeKey of nodeKeys" 
              [path]="nodePath" 
              [key]="nodeKey" 
              [level]="level+1" 
              [data]="data.node[nodeKey]">
           </node>
        </div>
    '
    ...
})
export class NodeComponent {
    @Input() key: string;
    @Input() data: any;
    @Input() level: number = 0;
    @Input() path: string = 'node';

    private nodePath: string;
    private nodeKeys: Array<string>;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.nodePath = this.path + '-' + this.key;
        if (this.data.node) {
            this.nodeKeys = Object.keys(this.data.node);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this running? Do you have error(s)? Whats the problem? I think there could be some issues. But I suggest you to come up with plunker!

Comment: Is working fine but I cannot access the clicked node component and it's data in my onClick function because it provides only the $event arg which is a DOM/MouseEvent. There is a comment (2 line) in that function about my issue. I think it is a conceptional question about how to get child component instance from parent's event handler?

Comment: simple how would you get data through `EventEmitter` unless you manually emit it ? If you want to get data in `Parentcmp`, you have to emit data from `childcmp`. second way if you want to access `childcmp` then you can go with `viewchild api`

Comment: But if I emitted event from a deep hierarchy I have to emit through all level until I reached the top. It isn't so effective, is it?